# Android Studio Crashes on Launch, El Capitan, freetype-related, fontmanager error?

Tags: android, macos, crash

After upgrading to the latest version, my Android Studio doesn't launch. 
Here's the part of  the log file

```
Process:               studio [1640]
Path:                  /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/studio
Identifier:            com.google.android.studio
Version:               3.0 (AI-171.4443003)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           studio [1640]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2018-01-24 15:02:22.935 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G19009)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        FC797067-FAA7-1DA5-F303-0A69791FA096

Sleep/Wake UUID:       16FABF54-4120-49B7-B042-6DCA0BA066CC

Time Awake Since Boot: 26000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       11000 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        29  Java: AWT-EventQueue-0 3.0#AI-171.4443003 Studio, eap:false, os

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0:: AppKit Thread  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff909c2f72 mach_msg_trap + 10
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff909c23b3 mach_msg + 55
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8db9b114 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 212
3   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8db9a5dc __CFRunLoopRun + 1356
4   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8db99e28 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
5   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8f67d935 RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
6   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8f67d76f ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
7   com.apple.HIToolbox             0x00007fff8f67d5af _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
8   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9856bdf6 _DPSNextEvent + 1067
9   com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9856b226 -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 454
10  libosxapp.dylib                 0x000000011e63601e -[NSApplicationAWT nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 121
11  com.apple.AppKit                0x00007fff9855fd80 -[NSApplication run] + 682
12  libosxapp.dylib                 0x000000011e635e65 +[NSApplicationAWT runAWTLoopWithApp:] + 222
13  libawt_lwawt.dylib              0x000000011e5bf7f4 -[AWTStarter starter:] + 869
14  com.apple.Foundation            0x00007fff9f521dbe __NSThreadPerformPerform + 279
15  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8dbbb7e1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
16  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8db9af0c __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
17  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8db9a42f __CFRunLoopRun + 927
18  com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff8db99e28 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
19  com.google.android.studio       0x00000001073e0d79 main + 336
20  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff9ec935ad start + 1

....

Thread 29 Crashed:: Java: AWT-EventQueue-0 3.0#AI-171.4443003 Studio, eap:false, os
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff909c8f06 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91e034ec pthread_kill + 90
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00007fff96d036df abort + 129
3   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000109947aa8 os::abort(bool) + 22
4   libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000109a50b2d VMError::report_and_die() + 2207
5   libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010994c116 JVM_handle_bsd_signal + 511
6   libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001099499dc signalHandler(int, __siginfo*, void*) + 45
7   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x00007fff9643552a _sigtramp + 26
8   dyld                            0x00007fff662e5ffc mach_vm_deallocate + 25
9   libfreetype.dylib.6             0x000000012107e805 tt_glyph_load + 4245
10  libfreetype.dylib.6             0x0000000121068b6d FT_Load_Glyph + 861
11  libfontmanager.dylib            0x0000000120f84954 Java_sun_font_FreetypeFontScaler_getGlyphImageNative + 383
12  ???                             0x0000000109f8e574 0 + 4462273908
13  ???                             0x0000000109f80b10 0 + 4462218000
14  ???                             0x0000000109f80b10 0 + 4462218000
15  ???                             0x0000000109f80b10 0 + 4462218000
16  ???                             0x0000000109f80b10 0 + 4462218000
17  ???                             0x0000000109f80be0 0 + 4462218208
18  ???                             0x0000000109f80be0 0 + 4462218208
19  ???                             0x000000010a384614 0 + 4466427412
20  ???                             0x0000000109f80a40 0 + 4462217792
21  ???                             0x0000000109f80a40 0 + 4462217792
22  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
23  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
24  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
25  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
26  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
27  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
28  ???                             0x0000000109f80e54 0 + 4462218836
29  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
30  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
31  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
32  ???                             0x0000000109f80e54 0 + 4462218836
33  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
34  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
35  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
36  ???                             0x0000000109f80e54 0 + 4462218836
37  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
38  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
39  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
40  ???                             0x0000000109f80e54 0 + 4462218836
41  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
42  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
43  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
44  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
45  ???                             0x0000000109f80e54 0 + 4462218836
46  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
47  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
48  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
49  ???                             0x0000000109f80e54 0 + 4462218836
50  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
51  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
52  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
53  ???                             0x0000000109f80e54 0 + 4462218836
54  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
55  ???                             0x0000000109f81042 0 + 4462219330
56  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
57  ???                             0x0000000109f81042 0 + 4462219330
58  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
59  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
60  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
61  ???                             0x0000000109f81042 0 + 4462219330
62  ???                             0x0000000109f81042 0 + 4462219330
63  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
64  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
65  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
66  ???                             0x0000000109f794e7 0 + 4462187751
67  libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001097d22fd JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 1431
68  libjvm.dylib                    0x000000010980fa92 JVM_DoPrivileged + 1368
69  ???                             0x0000000109f8e574 0 + 4462273908
70  ???                             0x0000000109f80d80 0 + 4462218624
71  ???                             0x0000000109f80e54 0 + 4462218836
72  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
73  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
74  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
75  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
76  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
77  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
78  ???                             0x0000000109f80ffd 0 + 4462219261
79  ???                             0x0000000109f794e7 0 + 4462187751
80  libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001097d22fd JavaCalls::call_helper(JavaValue*, methodHandle*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 1431
81  libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001097d1432 JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, KlassHandle, Symbol*, Symbol*, JavaCallArguments*, Thread*) + 318
82  libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001097d1571 JavaCalls::call_virtual(JavaValue*, Handle, KlassHandle, Symbol*, Symbol*, Thread*) + 87
83  libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000109816066 thread_entry(JavaThread*, Thread*) + 120
84  libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000109a17ac0 JavaThread::thread_main_inner() + 130
85  libjvm.dylib                    0x0000000109a17985 JavaThread::run() + 409
86  libjvm.dylib                    0x00000001099475d9 java_start(Thread*) + 250
87  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91e0099d _pthread_body + 131
88  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91e0091a _pthread_start + 168
89  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00007fff91dfe351 thread_start + 13
```

Thread number can be different, but it is always the thread with freetype and fontmanager dylibs. I think, this could be conflicting with brewary (brew), but I don't know how to fix that. I tried removing freetype from brew, but that did not help.

Comment: I have the exact problem, did you managed to solve this?

Comment: nope. but I found the following link: 
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/JRE-515

Answer (score 0):

I haven't had crashes with android studio as i always update my MacBook's OS,try updating your OS to the latest version(as of writing 10.13.2 MacOS High Sierra). Sometimes reinstalling android studio might solve your issue if the crash is causes by a interrupted install.

Comment: This would require upgrading my MBP first. It's a ten-years old machine, and El Capitan is the last officially supported os from Apple. I have tried reinstalling Android Studio, but it didn't help. Not sure if it was an interrupted install, but there was definitely something wrong with the 'downloading progress bar', which was mentioned also here on stackoverflow by other users, though, Google does not react and the bug is still there...